# Better illustrating error message for NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

Now the user only get a error message like "Error code 5".

```
NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code %i", [parseError code]];

UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
```

So the NSXMLParserError code is not enough for me. I rather would like something like "NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError" or "The document ended unexpectedly."

Is there an easy way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check NSError's `localizedDescription`, `localizedFailureReason` etc etc methods in [NSError class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-DontLinkElementID_11)

```
NSString *errorString = [parserError localizedDescription];
```

Comment: I've tried localizedDescription & Co before, but wasn't successful. I didn't get errorWithDomain:code:userInfo: working.

localizedDescription shows "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 512."
localizedFailureReason shows "null".
So no method left?

Comment: well if you can list down all the errors from the NSXMLParserErrorDomain which you specifically want to describe to the user, you can write a switch case comparing those errors from the Parser Error Constants, and then throw a general error message for the remaining errors in default..

Comment: thanks, I also though about this. I hoped there is an easier way or an existing solution.